# How to set up the system so that applications had to ask to get permission to launch an internet browser?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, permissions, browser

Many application have following behavior: If you click to some part of them they start your primary internet browser to show you something on their homepage. I want to change my windows settings (then I want do it in my second operating system Ubuntu) in that way so if any application tries to start an internet browser if I want it to be started (by some kind of pop up) and ask me if I want start it. (If this is not possible I would like to know a way to ban some application from starting a web browser at all.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a mini program (e.g. AutoIt or similar on Windows, Bash script on Ubuntu) and set it as the "default web browser". This program would then ask if you actually want to open your browser.

On Linux, protocol associations are desktop-environment-specific, if I remember correctly. On Windows, this entails setting the program as the default handler for the HTTP, HTTPS and possible FTP protocols.

**Update:** Example Bash script, untested(!)

```
#!/bin/bash
zenity --question --text="Are you sure you wish to proceed?" && firefox "$@"
```

This depends on `zenity`, a handy utility to show dialogs from the command line/scripts.

Comment: Could you show a script that will pass all the arguments right please? So there will not be blank page on browser if I really want to let program to open a browser after passing script. If you do it I will give you my bounty. To set it as a default browser I find this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/79305/how-do-i-change-my-default-browser)

Comment: Please see the updated post.